# Dagger2 android initialize graph at activity level

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I am creating a library for my application and in this library, i want to use dagger2 however since there can only be one application class so I dont't have an application class in my library  so the obvious thing came to my mind was to initialize dagger at activity level but i also want to use dagger android. This is what I have achieved this far i have initialized dagger but could not use dagger android.

```
Singleton
@Component(modules = [NetworkModule::class,
    MyModule::class], dependencies = [Dependency::class])
internal interface ActivityComponent {

 fun inject(activity: MyActivity)

}
```

My injector class

```
internal class Injector {

    companion object {
        private var deps: Dependency? = null

        fun inject(activity: MyActivity) {
            component = ActivityComponent
                    .builder()
                    .dependency(deps)
                    .build()
            component.inject(activity)
        }

        fun setDependency(dependency: Dependency) {
            this.deps = dependency
        }


    }
}
```

**MyActivity.class**

```
class MyActivity:AppCompatActivity{

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Injector.inject(this)
}

}
```

This works fine but how to use dagger android?
Because to use dagger android you need to initialize DaggerAppComponent in application class and i don't have one.

Comment: If your code is a library you can't use DaggerAndroid as that requires you have code in the Application class there no way around that. As a library developer if you want to be dagger friendly the best you can do is provide some modules and let the host app define components using that. If your library contains an activity then you can invoke AndroidInjection, but this will force any app using your library to use Dagger themselves.

Comment: So suppose we have Dagger at our application level but if I invoke android injector in an activity doesn't it mean that I am attaching my library level dependency to existing application dependency, but since it is a library it should have a different graph all-together and the dependencies we need from the application will just be passed during initialization?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you're developing a library there's no application (in general). If you're developing an internal library (which is only used by your application, or applications under your control) you're pretty much free to do what you prefer.